# Visual Studio CPU profiler can't load symbols when copied to a different machine

Tags: visual-studio, profiler, debug-symbols, cannot-find-symbol

So I made a profiling using Visual Studio 2022 CPU profiler on one machine. Then I copied the resulting `.diagsession` file to the local copy of the same project on another machine. But when I try to look at the methods it says `Symbols failed to load for <myproject_name>.dll. Failed to find symbol file <myproject_name>.pdb`.

I tried to include the `bin` folder (where both the `.dll` and `.pdb` files are located) of this project in the `Options > Debugging > Symbols` settings, but it does not work. Apparently, VS tries to load the symbols from the `Microsoft symbol server` and does not look in this folder.

What can I do to make the `Profiler` load the correct symbols for my project? Maybe I can see more detailed description of the proccess of loading the symbols somewhere (e.g. exact name of the folders that the `Profiler` is looking into) because information in the `Output` is not very elaborate?

P.S. Symbol loading on the first machine, where the profiling was initially made, is working fine.